# Effect of null conditional operator in comparison with default

Tags: c#, .net, default-value, .net-core-3.1, null-conditional-operator

I am wondering about the behavioral difference that can be seen in output for Test 2 on example below.

I'm on .NET Core 3.1 for this scenario.

```
using System;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new Customer();
        
        if (a.BirthDate == default)
            Console.WriteLine("Test 1 Result: default");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Test 1 Result: NOT default");
            
        
        if (a?.BirthDate == default)
            Console.WriteLine("Test 2 Result: default");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Test 2 Result: NOT default");
        
        
        if (a.BirthDate == default(DateTime))
            Console.WriteLine("Test 3 Result: default");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Test 3 Result: NOT default");
        
        
        if (a?.BirthDate == default(DateTime))
            Console.WriteLine("Test 4 Result: default");
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Test 4 Result: NOT default");
    }
}

public class Customer
{
    public DateTime BirthDate {get;set;}
}
```

Output:

```
Test 1 Result: default
Test 2 Result: NOT default
Test 3 Result: default
Test 4 Result: default
```

I was expecting all the outputs would be "default".

Comment: The type of `a?.BirthDate` is `DateTime?` (i.e. `Nullable<DateTime>`), no? So the check is equivalent to `a?.BirthDate == default(DateTime?)`

Comment: No, it didn't work as well...

Comment: @knittl, thanks for the response.

Actually, in Test 4, a?.BirthDate == default(DateTime) returns true. 

I just wonder why a?.BirthDate == default returns false, in Test 2.

Comment: `default(DateTime)` is different from `default(DateTime?)` (i.e. `default(Nullable<DateTime>)`)

Comment: @furkan.kaya when you use just `default` it works similarly to `var`, the compiler determines the type, which in the case of `Test 2` is `DateTime?` or `Nullable<DateTime>`. For the `Test 4` case you have explicitly cast to `DateTime`, hence the result `true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of [`default` literal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/default#default-literal) is inferred by the compiler. In the second test, the inferred type is `Nullable<DateTime>`, so it's equivalent to

```
a?.BirthDate == default(Nullable<DateTime>)
```

The default value of a [`Nullable<T>` type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-8.0) is `null`, you can check with the following code

```
Console.WriteLine(default(Nullable<DateTime>) == null); // true
```

Because the left operand is a real `DateTime` object, the comparison result is false.

Comment: Now I get it, so the condition

`a?.BirthDate == default` actually means `a?.BirthDate == null`, NOT `a?.BirthDate == JAN_1_0001`

That makes sense, thanks for the response.